# Implementing my own successor predicate

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I know Prolog has its own predicate to handle successors but I want to make my own for exercise.

Here is the code of my current positive successor :

```
successor(0,1).
successor(X,Y) :-
    X > 0,
    Xx is X-1;
    successor(Xx,Yx),
    Y is Yx + 1.
```

When I type `successor(O,1)`,
I have `true`
`successor(O,X)` returns
`X = 1`
`successor(X,1)` returns
`X = 0`
`successor(2,X)` returns
`X = 3`

The last thing that I don't succeed doing is

```
successor(X,2)
```

It throws and error :

```
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I did a trace and found out it is comparing an uninitialized variable (`X`) to `0`

It is because I'm asking for this but I have no clue on how to fix this to make the last call work and still have the other work too.

Comment: You will have issues with `>/2` and `is/2` when creating a relational `successor/2` predicate. `>/2`  expects *both* arguments to be instantiated. So if `X` is variable, `X > 2` will throw an error. The predicate `is/2` expects everything on the right hand side to be instantiated. So, even if `X > 2` worked, `Xx is X-1` will throw an error if `X` is variable because it needs to compute the expression to the right of `is`. Ways around it are (clunky): use `var/1` or `nonvar/1` to check for variables, or (better): use CLPFD operations, such as `X #> 0` and `Xx #= X - 1`.

Comment: Also, there's no need for `successor/2` to be recursive, unless you are looking for all `Y` such that `X < Y`, etc.

Comment: As a first step when learning Prolog, focus on [tag:successor-arithmetics]. You are using `(is)/2` and `(>)/2` which is way too moded for your first attempts.

Comment: Also note that [`succ/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#succ) is defined in many systems.

Answer (score 3):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `successor/2` like this:

```
successor(X0,X1) :-
   X0 #>= 0,
   X1 #= X0 + 1.
```

Sample queries:

```
?- successor(_,0).
false.

?- N #< 0, successor(N,_).
false.

?- successor(X,1).
X = 0.

?- successor(X,2).
X = 1.

?- successor(2,X).
X = 3.

?- successor(X,Y).
X in 0..sup, X+1 #= Y.
```

Comment: Perfect solution: Elegant, declarative, general, efficient. I shall call this an *EDGE* solution.

Comment: @false. Not on my metal: `?- successor(X,X).` gives 
`false.`

Comment: Actually, the naming could be better. What about `integer_successor/2`?

Comment: I would define the relation between integers and `s(X)` terms as: `integer_peano(0, 0). integer_peano(X, s(P)) :- X #> 0, X #= X0 + 1, integer_peano(X0, P).`. Usable in all directions etc. In fact, I would recommend to simply forget about `s(X)` terms entirely and use CLP(FD) constraints instead throughout: They are easier to understand and read, and completely declarative too.

Comment: `successor(X,Y), successor(Y,Z), X = Z.` succeeds also in SWI 7.3.4-11-g0a76568, whereas `Y = s(X), Z = s(Y), X = Z.` fails (with `set_prolog_flag(occurs_check,true).`)

Answer (score 1):

Why does your code care about the sign? You have 3 basic cases here, none of which are particularly concerned about where you stand with respect to zero on the number line:

- bound `X`; bound `Y`.
- bound `X`; unbound `Y`,
- unbound `X`; bound `Y`.

To that end...

```
successor(X,Y) :- int(X), int(Y), Y =:= X+1 .
successor(X,Y) :- int(X), var(Y), successor_x(X,Y) .
successor(X,Y) :- var(X), int(Y), predecessor_y(X,Y) .

successor_x(X,Y) :- T is X+1 , ( Y = T ; successor_x(T,Y) ) .

predecessor_y(X,Y) :- T is Y-1 , ( X = T ; predecessor_y(X,Y) ) .
```

Comment: `int/1` should better be `integer/1`, I guess.

Comment: And it incorrectly fails for `successor(X,Y)` implying that there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    successor(X,Y) :- var(X) -> X is Y - 1 ; Y is X + 1.
```

First checks if X is bound, then X is instantiated to Y - 1, else directly print Y as X + 1.

```
    ?- successor(90,L).
    L = 91.

    ?- successor(L,90).
    L = 89.

    ?- successor(L,-90).
    L = -91.

    ?- successor(-90,L).
    L = -89.
```

Comment: As a rule-of-thumb: Rather start with tests for the safe, instantiated case. Thus ` ( nonvar(X) -> ...`